# stl copy c++ проблема копирования

Tags: c++, stl, copy

Проблема при копировании с помощью `copy()`
Объявление:

```
copy(it, it, back_inserter(sell_medic));
```

Где it:

```
list<Medicine>::iterator it = medic.begin();
advance(it, id - 1);
```

Метод вообще не копирует в нужный `list <Medicine> sell_medic;`

Comment: Что именно вы хотели скопировать? Что значит `it, it`?

Comment: sell_medic.push_back(*it)  и все дела

Comment: Почему вы откатили правку, уточняющую заголовок вопроса? Сейчас ваш заголовок состоит из 3 используемых меток и предложения "проблема копирования", которое носит крайне общий характер. Человеку, который столкнулся с подобной проблемой, по текущему заголовку будет сложно найти ваш вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В алгоритмах стандартной библиотеки пара итераторов представляет диапазон - `[begin, end[` (end указывает на элемент за последним), поэтому диапазон `it, it` будет всегда представлять пустое множество. Если вы хотели скопировать с начала до `it` (но не включая элемент, на который `it` указывает) то код должен быть:

```
copy(medic.begin(), it, back_inserter(sell_medic));
```

> А если мне надо скопировать конкретный элемент, на который указывает этот итератор?

Тогда вам вообще не нужен `std::copy`:

```
sell_medic.push_back( *it );
```

но если сильно хочется:

```
std::copy(it, std::next(it), std::back_inserter(sell_medic));
```

ЗЫ этот код излишне многословен:

```
list<Medicine>::iterator it = medic.begin();
advance(it, id - 1);
```

проще написать так:

```
auto it = std::next( medic.begin(), id - 1 );
```

так и проще читать и короче [`std::next()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

Comment: А если мне надо скопировать конкретный элемент, на который указывает этот итератор?

Comment: `std::copy(it, it + 1, back_inserter(sell_medic));` но если вам всегда нужно копировать только один элемент в контейнер - не совсем понятно, зачем вам `std::copy`.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, там как минимум есть `advance(it, id - 1);`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker но такая арифметика с итераторами `list` не работает, я понял свою ошибку, я просто создал другой итератор и сделал диапазон в один элемент. А `copy` я использую, потому, что `list` из объектов класса `Medicine` и содержит несколько полей, поэтому мне так удобней копировать

Answer (score 1):

Если вам так уж хочется использовать стандартный алгоритм, то можно так:

```
copy_n(it, 1, back_inserter(sell_medic));
```